# How to start a REPL while debugging C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, lldb

How can I get a REPL to evaluate simple things and test things out in the middle of a program's execution in C++?

I have some debugging tools at my disposal, lldb, but as far as I can tell, I can only view things, not test new things on the fly, even though it seems like it should be able to do it but maybe that functionality of the lldb debugger only works for Swift.

It doesn't have to be a complete REPL, but the ability to do some basic things would be so incredibly helpful. I am working with a massive binary in a new codebase with all sorts of types, classes, composition, and inheritance going on that's overwhelming and undocumented, and every test and repeat of the 50GB binary is about 10 minutes which is painful (running unit tests takes the same 10 minutes). It would be great if I could test statements out in a REPL on a breakpoint in the middle of the execution, one statement after another to play around and figure things out faster.

I'm coming from a drop into ipython/ipdb background, as well as the same lldb for Swift. Very new to C++.

Comment: Visual Studio offers edit and continue function. However a better idea is to forget about REPL and interactive code typing as fast as possible.

Comment: @user7860670 What is your goto method for C++ for fast as possible feedback on what's going on and figuring things out? Log statements?

Comment: I guess i figure code structure from reading source code. So an IDE with semantic syntax highlighting is a must. Alternative tools such as woboq may generate neat source code web pages with nice annotations ([example](https://clickhouse.com/codebrowser/html_report/ClickHouse/src/Functions/generateUUIDv4.cpp.html)). Building these static web pages usually takes considerable time, however navigation is much faster because it does not require IDE to parse everything every time.

Answer (score 3):

The lldb command `expr` - aliased to `p` - should do what you want.  `expr` will run the code you provide "as though it had been inserted in the current context" and will return the expression's result.  So for instance, if you have a function and want to see what it returns for various inputs, you can do:

```
(lldb) expr my_new_function(10, 20, 30)
```

You can even debug functions while handling such interesting inputs by doing:

```
(lldb) break set -n my_new_function
(lldb) expr -i 0 -- my_new_function(10, 20, 30)
```

the `-i` tells lldb to stop on the breakpoint, by default lldb ignores breakpoints in hand called functions.

You can also define new objects & structs in the expression command, but unlike the Swift REPL mode(*) user-defined objects, functions & variables have to be named with an initial `$` to keep them from getting confused with names from your code.  For instance, if you have a class A:

```
(lldb) expr A $myA()
```

will make a default-constructed object of type A, then you can call methods on it:

```
(lldb) expr $myA().doSomething()
```

Note that C++ templates are poorly described in debug information - the current standard only describes instantiations and not the abstract template form.  So YMMV when trying to create objects of complex template types.  The other danger with C++ is that some functions you want to call may only exist as inlined code, which the debugger can't invoke.  This happens for some of the STL types, e.g. the size() method is often not callable on vectors & the like because it's always inlined.  That's less of a problem with -O0 code, however.

(*) When you run `swift` in Terminal w/o arguments to bring up the Swift REPL, you are actually just running lldb in a fancy input mode that feeds what you type to the `expr` command under the covers.  The main difference between the bare `expr` and the full Swift REPL is that the REPL is focused on making new code, whereas `expr` is more meant for exploring the code you are stopped in right now, so the name lookup rules are different.  There isn't a full C++ REPL mostly because we don't know how to do jobs like "build C++ classes incrementally", which would be required for a real REPL.

Comment: I see! But there's no making a new function on the fly in a REPL because it can't be build incrementally? This still helps a lot, thank you

Comment: You can actually use the REPL to make new C functions.  There's a little trick because C/C++ doesn't allow interior functions, so you can't put a function definition in the construct lldb uses to emulate the context of the current frame.  But `expr --top-level --` compiles the expression outside any frame, and function definition is allowed in that context.  But that only works for free functions, not methods.

Comment: I see, thanks! Sorry on the delay for approving this answer btw, I will do so very soon after I have a chance to play through it, the answer seems fantastic.